# Accepting special characters in querystring

Tags: htaccess, apache

Currently, the request ends with Forbidden error when having a querystring parameter value that looks like an SQL command (for instance if it contains `'` and `and`):

```
domain.com/path/to/page?foo=a%27%20or%20%27a
```

Instead, this should be a valid url that should open the page. I think the issue should be fixed in the `.htaccess` file. Currently the `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]

# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Force Download Rule
<FilesMatch "\.(mp4|mp3|jpg|jpeg|pdf|png|tif|mobi|epub|azk)">
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /dl/">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-disposition "attachment"
</If>
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Somewhere we should whitelist these special characters such as `%27` and special SQL keywords (such as `and`). Adding this line before the first `RewriteCond` line, didn't make any change:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|drop|delete|update|cast|create|char|convert|alter|declare|order|script|set|md5|benchmark|encode) [NC,OR]
```

(that was taken from [this page](http://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/apostrophe-single-quote-code-character/))

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try using the `b` switch. Let me get you back with the documentation link.

Comment: @PraveenKumar What do you mean? Where should I add the `b`?

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, it's not because of that... The url is already encoded, but it failes with a `403` when using SQL keywords and simple quotes. I'm not sure where these are set actually...

Comment: I can't not reproduce your issue. I guess that the "Forbidden error" is a 403 HTTP status code, right? You may need to contact with your hosting provider.

Comment: This might be a protection against possible SQL injections vulnerabilities, maybe the host is using some mod_security settings or other kind of security checks ?

Comment: @birgire I also think it's SQL related, but I guess by turning it off it won't hurt the server because there are other layers of security there. I'm waiting the response from the hosting provider...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `mod_security` blocks your requests. To check it installed or not run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check here:
[image]

If so, you should contact your hosting provider or administrator.

Comment: I don't see any of these (I don't even see the `apache2handler` there). Also, cannot find on the page anything containing `security` or `loaded modules`.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Could you confirm that you use apache? What version? And which SAPI for PHP ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php ) do you use?

Comment: That's useful information. In this case, like you said, the hosting provider will take care of the issue. Thanks!